# DocumentFile not recognized API 22 Android

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I try to use the new ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE feature in Lollipop.
I try some code i found and i have the following problem:

"DocumentFile" is not recognized

[image]

My Api Level 22 in Eclipse is

[image]

Any hints ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DocumentFile` is part of support library, so you must include one in your project:

```
DocumentFile
java.lang.Object
   ↳ android.support.v4.provider.DocumentFile
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/provider/DocumentFile.html